# Best way to save SQL versions while working on Tableau?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

I am working using Tableau and have to write down multiple different SQL each time, while making new data sources.
I have to save all changes on SQL for every data source.
Currently I would paste the SQL on notepad and save them on separate folder in my computer, along with description of the changes.
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Do you ever reuse the SQL? The first step to being organised is saving the SQL as a view on the database server. Then you point your report at the view. This is just the start of moving towards a managed reporting solution

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have permission to create objects in the database, begin by creating database views, As @Nick.McDermaid commented.

Then, instead of using Custom SQL data source in Tableau, just connect to the View as if it were a table.

If you need to track the changes to these SQL views of your data, you will need to learn how to use source control for the .sql files that can be scripted from within SQL Server Management Studio:
[image]

Your company or school may have a preferred source control system already in use, in which case you should use that. If they don't, or if you are learning at home, then Git and Subversion are popular open source choices.

There are many courses available on learning platforms like Coursera that will teach you how to learn how to use those systems.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem as you.

We ended up writing the queries in SQL Editor SQL Work bench (https://www.sql-workbench.eu/), then managed the code history and performed code peer-review (logic, error check, etc) in team shared space (like confluence).

The reasons we did that is

1) SQL queries are much easy to write on Work Bench
2) Code review is a must! You will find through implementing a review process more mistakes than you could ever think about
3) The shared space is just really convenient as it is accessible by everyone, and all errors are documented. After sometimes you get a lot of visible knowledge accumulated.

I also totally agree with Nick as this is one step to a reporting solution. But developing a whole reporting server is heavy, costly and takes time. Unless management are really convinced of the importance of developing a reporting solution, you may have to get a workaround with queries and Tableau (at least that was the case for us)

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I would suggest you simply version the tableau workbook.  The contents of the workbook are XML, so perfect for versioning using file based tools (Dropbox, One Drive, etc.) or source control (git, etc.).  The workbooks themselves are usually quite small, so just make sure to keep the extract data separate if you use it.